# Pasar información a .php con .ajax usando serialize()

Tags: php, javascript, jquery, html, ajax

tengo el siguiente código que sólo funciona a veces sin seguir ninguna norma fija por lo que supongo que es algo que está mal que provoca que el comportamiento sea impredecible, por favor necesito ayuda. Gracias.

**----He colocado el php en css porque no sabía donde colocarlo**

```js
$('#inscripcionform').submit(function(event) {
  event.preventDefault();
   $.ajax({
        url: "sheets/php/mail.php/",
        type: 'POST',
        data: $(this).serialize(),
        success: function(data) {
    successForm();
        }
    });
  }
```

```css
php

<?php
/* Set e-mail recipient */
$myemail  = "prueba@yahoo.es";
$subject = "PRUEBAS";

$nombre  = $_POST['elnombre'];
$email  = $_POST['elemail'];
$telefono    = $_POST['eltelefono'];
$relacion  = $_POST['larelacion'];
$comentario  = $_POST['loscomentarios'];

/* Let's prepare the message for the e-mail */
$message = "Hola :

Nueva inscripción :

Nombre: $nombre
E-mail: $email
Teléfono: $telefono
Relación con la enfermedad: $relacion

Comentario:
$comentario


Un beso!
";

/* Send the message using mail() function */
$success = mail($myemail, $subject, $message);

exit();

?>
```

```html
<form method="post" class="child_form" id="inscripcionform" name="inscripcionform" action="sheets/php/mail.php/" >
            <p>
                <label>Nombre y Apellidos:</label>
            </p>
            <p>
                <input type="text" name="elnombre" class="formbox" onclick="this.value=''" />
                <span></span>
            </p>
            <p>
                <label>Correo electrónico:</label>
            </p>
            <p>
                <input type="email" name="elemail" class="formbox" onclick="this.value=''" />
                <span></span>
            </p>
            <p>
                <label>Teléfono</label>
            </p>
            <p>
                <input type="text" name="eltelefono" class="formbox" onclick="this.value=''" />
                <span></span>
            </p>
            <p>
                <label>Relación:</label>
            </p>
            <p>
                <input type="text" name="larelacion" class="formbox" onclick="this.value=''" />
                <span></span>
            </p>
            <p>
                <label>Comentarios:</label>
            </p>
            <p>
                <input type="text" name="loscomentarios" value="Información adicional. Con un máximo de 142 caracteres." class="formbox" style="height:120px;" onclick="this.value=''" />
                <span></span>
            </p>
            <p>
                <button type="submit" form="inscripcionform" value="Enviar" class="submit">Enviar</button>
                <span></span>
            </p>
        </form>
```

Comment: Cuando dices que se comparta de forma extraña (aleatoriamente), ¿a que te refieres? ¿A veces el correo llega y a veces no? ¿Te da un error?

Comment: Hola @Sakrow , el problema es que a veces el correo llega con las variables vacías aunque hayan sido rellenadas (lo he hecho personalmente) y en otras ocasiones llega a la perfección...

Comment: Buenas, ¿te valió la respuesta?

Answer (score 1):

Lo primero que cambiaría del código es la forma en la que generas el correo electrónico, lo mejor que puedes hacer es usar `EOT`:

http://php.net/manual/es/language.types.string.php

Después de eso, poner entre llaves las variables, para delimitarlas dentro del texto, de esa manera no hay error posible, por ejemplo la generación del cuerpo del correo seria:

```
$message = <<<EOT 

   Hola :

   Nueva inscripción :

   Nombre: {$nombre}
   E-mail: {$email}
   Teléfono: {$telefono}
   Relación con la enfermedad: {$relacion}

   Comentario:
   {$comentario}

   Un beso!
EOT;
```

Con esto te vas a quitar los primeros posibles problemas. Después quedaría por comprobar que las variables se están enviando correctamente, para eso, lo que te recomiendo es que hagas un poco de `debug`, añadiendo una linea al `js`:

```
$('#inscripcionform').submit(function(event) {
    event.preventDefault();
    $data = $(this).serialize();
    console.log($data);
    $.ajax({
        url: "sheets/php/mail.php/",
        type: 'POST',
        data: data,
        success: function(data) {
                successForm();
        }
    });
}
```

Con eso sabes exactamente como se van a enviar las variables (`nombre => valor`) de manera que contrastas que esta escritas correctamente.

En la parte de `PHP` debes de hacer lo mismo (`var_dump($_POST)`), para descartar que ese sea el error, que en este caso puede ser que por alguna cosa no se envían con valor, o que los nombres no son correctos.

Para forzar que los `input` tengan valor lo mejor que puedes hacer es ponerle un `required` en el `HTML`

https://www.w3schools.com/tags/att_input_required.asp

Dinos que te dice el `debug` por si nos hemos saltado alguna cosa.